# override jquery mobile body background-color

Tags: html, css

How can I override the CSS of body using below custom style if the page require linked with the

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />

<style>
body {
   background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

I tried to save the custom style in custom.css and declare it like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css" />
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if it's not loading a more specific rule like `body.someclassname`, or use the `important` rule: `body{background:red !important;}`

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing the rest of your page, but have you tried:

```
body {
   background-color: red !important;
}
```